# Joomla 3 MVC platform 12.1 custom component template override

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, components, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I'm working with Joomla 3's MVC 12.1 platform and running into some issues with getting template overrides to work.

My Component has 3 controllers: stores, coupons, sales.

For each of these controllers I call my view similiar to this:

```
$paths = new SplPriorityQueue;
$paths->insert(JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$app->getTemplate().'/html/com_stores/stores', 'normal');
$paths->insert(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/stores/tmpl', 'normal');

$view = new StoresViewsStores(new StoresModelsStore, $paths);
$view->setLayout('default');

// Render our view.
echo $view->render();
```

Only deference between them is switching the view/model/directories out respectively.

As long as I don't include any overrides in my template everything works as expected. However as soon as I include overrides things get wonky.

If I add a `com_stores/stores/default.php` into my template, my stores get overridden correctly however the coupons and sales controllers start pointing to the stores override instead of their own folders.

Is their something that i'm missing that is making each of the controllers point to the same override?

Just for reference here is what is in for the paths in each controller.

Stores:

```
$paths->insert(JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$app->getTemplate().'/html/com_stores/stores', 'normal');
$paths->insert(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/' . $viewName . '/tmpl', 'normal');
```

Sales:

```
$paths->insert(JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$app->getTemplate().'/html/com_stores/sales', 'normal');
$paths->insert(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/' . $viewName . '/tmpl', 'normal');
```

Coupons:

```
$paths->insert(JPATH_SITE.'/templates/'.$app->getTemplate().'/html/com_stores/coupons', 'normal');
$paths->insert(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/views/' . $viewName . '/tmpl', 'normal');
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: have you read http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core ?

Comment: The issue didn't lie with how to override something, It was with how to properly set the paths in the new MVC framework. 

Later as I described in my answer I found that the controller wasn't being set properly which was making my all my views point to the same override.

Comment: You are not using the new mvc if you have controllers named stores. THe new mvc has controllers with names like save, put, get, copy and other verbs.

Comment: This is a front end component that I don't need to save,put, blah blah blah; naming conventions aside its the new framework classes i'm using to extend from, instead of appending Legacy to things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solutions. I started by tracing through The component to see what being loaded. Turns out everything was being forced through my stores controller. So I made a slight change in how my component checks to see which controller to use.

`$controller = $app->input->get('controller','stores');`

to

`$controller = $app->input->get('view','stores');`

One thing to note is that all of my views match match my controller name perfectly so i didn't have to do anything special to know this will work.